# MySQL Upgrade Procedure in a production environment

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, mysql-5.7, upgrade

Am new to the role and employers have asked me to come up with a plan to upgrade the MySQL 5.6 on the production server to 5.7. It has partitions and MASTER-MASTER replication setup and has around 10TB of data.i couldn't find proper documentation on internet. Can you guys help please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Disk partitioning?  Or table `PARTITIONing`?

Comment: Do you have any Replicas hanging off the dual-Primary setup?

Answer (score 2):

Consider these stepping stones:

```
5.6M <-> 5.6M  (now)
5.6M <-> 5.6M -> 5.7S  (This will flesh out new reserved words, etc)
Revise code (see below)
5.6M <-> 5.6M -> 5.7S  -> 5.7S  (further test)
                 5.7M  -> 5.7S  (move IP addresses or whatever)
                 5.7M <-> 5.7M  (re-establish dual-Primary)
```

Note:  This requires acquiring 2 new machines -- thereby allowing for a hardware/OS upgrade at the same time.  Then the old pair of machines can be recycled/repurposed/donated.

"Revise code" -- Some incompatibilities are best handled by changing the app code.  For example, something that was deprecated in 5.6 and removed in 5.7 could be "fixed" in your code.  Then you could run the revised 5.6 setup to verify things before getting back to the 5.7 upgrade.

Be aware that the next upgrade (to 8.0) will be a much bigger step.  I recommend you start planning for that right after finishing this upgrade.

Also keep in mind the possibilities of moving to MariaDB, optionally with Galera (instead of dual-Primary).

Answer (score 1):

Converted from comments:

> As a first step, it would be good to test the upgrade process using a VM. If one cannot be easily made, then upgrading either a development or UAT environment would allow you to see what might break, what might be deprecated, and what might happen with some of the queries, procedures, triggers, etc. - [matigo](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/228577/matigo)

> backups backups backups and see urgently https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-upgrade.html  as it after removing the replication and partioning it is a normal upgrade for both servers, but still do this on new hardware, so that your system runs despite all problems - [nbk](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/190821/nbk)

Comment: What is your point about "partitioning"?